# Spaghetti plot in R, with different measurement times

Tags: r, plot

I have a data matrix called scores.csv that looks something like this:

```
ID      score   age
```

```
1       23       12  
1       50       16  
2       25       13  
2       67       16
```

I've used the following code:

```
scores<-read.table("scores.csv",sep=",", header=T)
interaction.plot(scores$age,scores$id, scores$score, xlab="age",ylab="score", legend=F)
```

This works fine if for all ID's the ages are the same so (12 & 16 for both) however once these are different I get an empty spaghetti plot.

Comment: are you open to ggplot2 ?

Comment: I am! I've seen a ggplot2 implemantation that just added 0 as start point for every ID but that's not really what I'm looking for,

Comment: Could you dput you matrizx or part of it ?

Comment: df <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                 Score=c(23,50,25,67,22,55),
                 Age=c(12,16,13,16,12,17))

Comment: This is all I can give you, the real data is confidential

Comment: Will `library(lattice); xyplot(Score ~ Age, group=ID, data=df, type="l")` give you what you want?

Comment: it does! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, here's with `ggplot2`

Be sure you're using a `data.frame`, not a `data.table`

```
library("ggplot2")    
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3), Score=c(23,50,25,67,22,55), Age=c(12,16,13,16,12,17))
    ggplot(df,aes(x=Age,y=Score,
             group=ID,color=factor(ID)))+
         geom_point()+geom_line()
```

[image]

And lattice (ekstroem deserves the credit for this one)

```
library(lattice); xyplot(Score ~ Age, group=ID, data=df, type="l")
```

[image]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTdnt.png)

I have used default aesthetics for this plots, you might want to customize adding other parameters.